# How to Store Rows from CSV File into Python and Print Data with HTML

Tags: python, html, excel, csv

Basically my problem is this: I have a CSV excel file with info on Southpark characters and I and I have an HTML template and what I have to do is take the data by rows (stored in lists) for each character and using the HTML template given implement that data to create 5 seperate HTML pages with the characters last names.

Here is an image of the CSV file: i.imgur.com/rcIPW.png

This is what I have so far:

```
askfile = raw_input("What is the filename?")

southpark = []

filename = open(askfile, 'rU')

for row in filename:
    print row[0:105]

filename.close()
```

The above prints out all the info on the IDLE shell in five rows but I have to find a way to separate each row AND column and store it into a list (which I don't know how to do). It's pretty rudimentary code I know I'm trying to figure out a way to store the rows and columns first, then I will have to use a function (def) to first assign the data to the HTML template and then create an HTML file from that data/template..and I'm so far a noob I tried searching through the net but I just don't understand the stuff.

I am not allowed to use any downloadable modules but I can use things built in Python like import csv or whatnot, but really its supposed to be written with a couple functions, list, strings, and loops..

Once I figure out how to separate the rows and columns and store them then I can work on implementing into HTML template and creating the file.

I'm not trying to have my HW done for me it's just that I pretty much suck at programming so any help is appreciated!

BTW I am using Python 2.7.2 and if you want to DL the CSV file click [here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Projects/proj06.dir/southPark.csv).

---

UPDATE:

Okay, thanks a lot! That helped me understand what each row was printing and what info is being read by the program. Now since I have to use functions in this program somehow this is what I was thinking.

Each row (0-6) prints out separate values, but just the print row function prints out one character and all his corresponding values which is what I need. What I want is to print out data like "print row" would but I have to store each of those 5 characters in a separate list.

Basically "print row" prints out all 5 characters with each of their corresponding attributes, how can I split each of them into 5 variables and store them as a list?

When I do print row[0] it only prints out the names, or print row[1](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Projects/proj06.dir/southPark.csv) only prints the DOB. I was thinking of creating a def function that takes only print "row" and splits into 5 variables in a loop and then another def function takes those variables/lists of data and combines them with the HTML template, and at the end I have to figure out how to create HTML files in Python..

Sorry if I sound confusing just trying to make sense of it all. This is my code right now it gives an error that there are too many values to unpack but I am just trying to fiddle around and try different things and see if they work. Based on what I wanted to do above I will probably have to delete all most of this code and find a way to rewrite it with list type functions like .append or .strip, etc which I am not very familiar with..

```
import csv

original = file('southpark.csv', 'rU')

reader = csv.reader(original)

# List of Data
name, dob, descript, phrase, personality, character, apparel = []

count = 0

def southparkinfo():
for row in reader:
    count += 1
    if count == 0:
        row[0] = name
        print row[0] # Name (ex. Stan Marsh)
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 1:
        row[1] = dob
        print row[1] # DOB
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 2:
        row[2] = descript
        print row[2] # Descriptive saying (ex. Respect My Authoritah!)
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 3:
        row[3] = phrase
        print row[3] # Catch Phrase (ex. Mooom!)
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 4:
        row[4] = personality
        print row[4] # Personality (ex. Jewish)
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 5:
        row[5] = character
        print row[5] # Characteristic (ex. Politically incorrect)
        print "----------------"
    elif count == 6:
        row[6] = apparel
        print row[6] # Apparel (ex. red gloves)
    return

reader.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you go through the lecture notes? I'm sure your prof. must have covered some simple data munging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First and foremost, have a look at the [CSV docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).**

Once you understand the basics take a look at this code. This should get you started on the right path:

```
import csv

original = file('southpark.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(original)

for row in reader:
    #will print each row by itself (all columns from names up to what they wear)
    print row
    print "-----------------"
    #will print first column (character names only)
    print row[0]
```

You want to `import csv` module so you can work with the CSV filetype. Open the file in universal newline mode and read it with csv.reader. Then you can use a `for` loop to begin iterating through the rows depending on what you want. The first `print row` will print a single line of all a single character's data (ie: everything from their name up to their clothing type) like so:

```
['Stan Marsh', 'DOB: October 19th', 'Dude!', 'Aww #$%^!', 'Star Quarterback', 'Wendy', 'red gloves']

-----------------
['Kyle Broflovski', 'DOB: May 26th', 'Kick the baby!', 'You ***!', 'Jewish', 'Canadian', 'Ushanka']
-----------------
['Eric Theodore Cartman', 'DOB: July 1', 'Respect My Authroitah!', 'Mooom!', 'Big-boned', 'Political
ly incorrect', 'Knit-cap!']
-----------------
['Kenny McCormick', 'DOB: March 22', 'DOD: Every other week', 'Mmff Mmff', 'MMMFFF!!!', 'Mysterion!'
, 'Orange Parka']
-----------------
['Leopold Butters Stotch', 'DOB:Younger than the others!', 'The 4th friend', 'Professor chaos', 'stu
tter', 'innocent', 'nerdy']
-----------------
```

Finally, the second statement `print row[0]` will provide you with the character names only. You can change the number and you'll be able to grab the other data as necessary. Remember, in a CSV file everything starts at 0, so in your case you can only go up to 6 because `A=0, B=1, C=2, etc...` To see these outputs more clearly, it's probably best if you comment out one of the `print` statements so you get a clearer picture of what you are grabbing.

```
-----------------
Stan Marsh
-----------------
Kyle Broflovski
-----------------
Eric Theodore Cartman
-----------------
Kenny McCormick
-----------------
Leopold Butters Stotch
```

**Note** I threw in that `print "-----------------"` so you would be able to see the different outputs.
Hope this helps you get you off to a start.

***Edit*** To answer your second question: The easiest way (although probably not the best way) to grab all of a single character's info would be to do something like this:

```
import csv

original = file('southpark.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(original)

stan = reader.next()
kyle = reader.next()
eric = reader.next()
kenny = reader.next()
butters = reader.next()

print eric
```

which outputs:

```
['Eric Theodore Cartman', 'DOB: July 1', 'Respect My Authroitah!', 'Mooom!', 'Big-boned', 'Politically incorrect', 'Knit-cap!']
```

Take note that if your CSV is modified such that the order of the characters are moved (ex: butters is moved to top) you will output the info of another character.